# Check a record exists in mysql

Tags: mysql

Assume I have following three tables.

```
Staff 

id | name
---------
1    Tom
2    Mary
```

```
Fulltime staff

id | name
---------
1    Tom
```

```
Parttime staff

id | name
---------
2    Mary
```

Is there a way I can display like this using SQL? Or should I add one more column in the Staff table?

```
Mysql

id | name | Work nature
----------------------
1    Tom    Fulltime
2    Mary   Parttime
```

Comment: Having `Staff` table `enum('Parttime', 'Fulltime')` would make more sense as structure.

Comment: Please see Mysql Joins https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want people to have different names when they're full time vs part time, do not repeat people's names.

There's nothing preventing someone from being both full and part time. Or neither. Instead of three tables, have one.

```
create table staff (
  id bigint primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  type enum('fulltime', 'parttime') not null
)
```

Now each person can only be one type of employee, the names are not repeated, and your select is trivial.